# How the CAN message is re-transmitted after arbitration

Tags: can-bus

I understand the CAN arbitration process. But I am very curious about how the Node which loses the arbitration re-transmit its message until success.

As I know many CAN messages are repeatably send on the CAN bus. For example, Node A and Node B simultaneously send messages every 100ms. 
Assuming Node A has low identifier value and Node B has high identifier value, then Node A will always win the arbitration and repeatably send message on CAN bus. As Node A and Node B send the message always at the same time, seems Node B will always lose the arbitration and the message can not reach to other Nodes forever...

What CAN mechanism is used for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Node B will try again when Node A ends the tx, which happens much earlier than 100ms.